# ¿ Como dar padding horizontal a la tienda de WooCommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, padding

Estoy tratando de aumentar el padding que existe entre los productos de la tienda y el borde de la pagina y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

Claro que la barra de navegación debe ocupar todo el ancho de la pagina
Cuando añado lo siguiente, el contenido se desplaza a la izquierda y queda todo el padding  ala derecha de la pagina :

```
.shop-container { padding: auto; width: 80%;}
```

Con el siguiente ejemplo, consigo que se haga el padding de `20px`, pero me gustaría que esto se ajustara a dispositivos móviles

```
.shop-container {  padding-left: 20px!important; padding-right:20px;}
```

¿ Como puedo hacer esto y que la pagina siga siendo responsiva?

Espero puedan ver lo que consigo con esto

```css
body {
  background: #08f;
}


#relleno {
  background-color: #360;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px; 
  border-width: 0;
  /* padding-left:40px;
   padding-right:40px; */
  height: 100%;
  padding: auto;
width:80%
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="relleno">Este contenedor tiene contenido y un relleno (padding) de 5 pixeles.
      Este contenedor tiene contenido y un relleno (padding) de 5 pixeles.
      Este contenedor tiene contenido y un relleno (padding) de 5 pixeles.
      Este contenedor tiene contenido y un relleno (padding) de 5 pixeles.
      Este contenedor tiene contenido y un relleno (padding) de 5 pixeles.
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que necesitas usar `margin` en lugar de `padding`. El `margin` te separa los elementos desde el borde del elemento hacia afuera, en cambio el `padding` agrega espacio del borde del elemento hacia adentro.

```css
body {
  background: #08f;
}

#relleno {
  background-color: #360;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="relleno">Este contenedor tiene contenido y un relleno (padding) de 5 pixeles. Este contenedor tiene contenido y un relleno (padding) de 5 pixeles. Este contenedor tiene contenido y un relleno (padding) de 5 pixeles. Este contenedor tiene contenido y un relleno (padding) de 5 pixeles. Este contenedor tiene contenido y un relleno (padding) de 5 pixeles.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo @DjCrazy. Exactamente con tu código no lo he conseguido, ya que  se mostraba la web en una caja con un margen muy feo.
Pero gracias a tu idea, he buscado la clase que contiene a las paginas de la tienda y le he añadido ese estilo.
gracias

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido. Es genial que hayas logrado comprender la idea y adaptarla a tu necesidad puntual. en ocasiones es difícil dar una respuesta 100% acertada ya que desconocemos el contexto del proyecto real del PO, pero hacemos lo que podemos con la información que tenemos. Estamos para apoyar nuestro aprendizaje colectivo. Sigue adelante!